# not language specific: Use "status variables"instead of returning status parameters?

Tags: coding-style

This is a question I was thinking about for years, take the following example into consideration for all other cases where this applies:

Let's say you have a button and depending on its visibility you want to change it to the other state, visible->invisible, invisible->visible

Someone who didn't read the documentation of the class he is using would probably go for

```
Button button;
bool visible;

public onTouch(){

if(visible){
    button.setVisibility(invisible)
    visible=false;} 
else{
    button.setVisibility(visible)
    visible=true;}
}
```

Which would work out great. However, in most languages, UI classes offer something like `Button.getVisibility` which would result in the following code:

```
Button button;

public onTouch(){

if(button.getVisibility==visible){
    button.setVisibility(invisible)} 
else{
    button.setVisibility(visible)}
}
```

Which needs less lines and if Visibility was a boolean the onTouch() could even be a one-liner. On the other hand you make a method call, the method takes time to return the value and this, on a large scale would result in a little delay and therefore make the GUI a tiny little bit unresponsive.

How do you deal with that? Is that something to care about or did the time I invest in writing this question already exceed all the little CPU cycles users ever experienced by "waiting" for the button to return a tiny parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the second option and only worry about if I had some evidence that this was a performance bottleneck. The cost is probably insignificant and the compiler may optimize it away anyway.

There is also a cost to maintaining a separate `visible` variable as well, both in terms of performance, but more importantly in complexity of making sure it is kept in-sync with the `button`

Perhaps `Button` should have a `toggleVisibility()` method.